# @RenderPage - Render a edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, render

I want to render a page but that page be a "edit" page. Something like this

```
@RenderPage("~/Views/Edit/25.cshtml")
```

But this doesn't work and probably i should pass the parameter "25" as a parameter, but so far without success. In my program I've got two tabs and both call(render) pages throw Ajax (Jqueryui - http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and i would like to when i click in a tab he call the edit view with a specific id.

It's possible? How i should do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render tabs via ajax in asp.net mvc you can do it this way.

CSHTML:

Create tab control, each anchor in tab header uses different routevalues. Ofcourse you can link them to different actions of controller:

```
<div id=tabs>
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab1", "Edit", new { id = 25 })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab2", "Edit", new { id = 26 })</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller, note that you are returning a partial view here which gets rendered into the tabcontrol:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // You probably want to load the Model from the db with id param. I just write a message
        ViewBag.Message = id;

        return PartialView("Edit"); 
    }
```

My partialview Edit.cshtml:

```
<span>Edit me @ViewBag.Message</span>
```

Javascript, just create your tab control normally:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

Generally if you want to render some partial view with parameters I'd personally go for

```
@Html.Action("Edit", "Controller", new {id=25})
```

Comment: Thanks. This "@Html.Action("Edit", "Controller", new {id=25})" ends up solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some actions to be performed on click for the specific tab then i would suggest you should go with Ajax.
Have a look to jQuery.Ajax.
Or else you want it a pure http web request, then you can have certain query string to be passed on the same page when user clicks on the tab and load the content accordingly by identified the passed value.